# How To change/ edit category products position programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, products, category-products

I would like to set position-numbers of category products in one specific category according to sku instead of 0 (default).

```
Magento version 1.9
```

I have a csv including position with sku.
EX : **"42-140107",
"43-140108",**

```
42 : Position,

140107 : Sku
```

I Tried smething Like below

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$categoryId = 156; //replace with your category id
$newPosition = ""; //To Be set according to sku
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();
//I Want to get the sku like above we getting the position
$all_products = $category->getProducts();


foreach ($products as $id=>$value){

    $products[$id] = $newPosition;//This $newPosition will change according to sku
}
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
$category->save();
```

My question is how to get the product sku & position from a relevant category and update the new position for category products?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change foreach code as below:

```
foreach ($products as $id=>$value){

    $products[$id] = $newPosition;//This $newPosition will change according to sku
}
```

Replace to:

```
foreach ($products as $id=>$value){
    $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getSku();
    $products[$id] = $newPosition;//This $newPosition will change according to sku
}
```

You have used **setPostedProducts** it will save your new position.If you want to check more you need to check class **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category** go to method **_saveCategoryProducts** you will get more information there.

This code will save category_id, product_id and new position in **catalog_category_product** table

Comment: Thank you very much , Your answer help me to find the sku of the category products.I am working on it and i will update my task also as an answer